# ejs error saying could not find matching id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

am new to mongoDB and eJS, am trying to display the content according to the collection id click, if i console the id am getting the id but if am pushing the content to the detials am getting an error: Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=". please what am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code

//my app.js file

```
app.get("/blogs/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id

    console.log(id)

    Blog.findById(id)
    .then((result) => {
        res.render('details', {title: "details page", blog: result})
    })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

my details file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <%- include("./partial/head.ejs") -%>
<body>
  <div class="singleblog-page">
    <%- include("./partial/nav.ejs") -%>
    
    
    <div class="single-blog">
        <h1><%=blog.title></h1>
        <p><%=blog.body></p>
    </div>

    <%- include("./partial/footer.ejs") -%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't close ejs tags for these two lines -

```
<h1><%=blog.title></h1>
<p><%=blog.body></p>
```

Close the tags and the problem will be solved. This site is helpful if you are new to ejs: https://ejs.co/

```
<h1><%= blog.title %></h1>
<p><%= blog.body %></p>
```